# How can I turn off current line highlighting in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

I've been looking for half an hour over all the options several times but I can't find it; googling also fails me at the moment. This is on Netbeans 6.0.1

Comment: Just change highlight color to the background color.

Answer (score 37):

Tools > options > highlighting > highlight caret row : [change background to inherited]

[image]
Screenshot : http://d.pr/wZpr